# error: no matching function for call to 'Node::Node()' - second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)

Tags: c++, struct, unordered-map

I've defined a structure like this:

```
struct Node
{
   int32_t a;
   int32_t b;
   double c;
   double d;
 
   Node (int32_t a, int32_t b, double c)
   {
     this->a = a;
     this->b = b;
     this->c = c;
     this->d = 0.0;
   }
};
```

I'm implementing a map of map like this:

```
unordered_map<UInt32,unordered_map<int32_t,Node>> data;
```

Upon using the below code. I'm receiving error `error: no matching function for call to 'Node::Node()' second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)`

```
data[instId][id].d += (value);
```

Please help out why I'm receiving error. I've also tried using `auto& tree = data[instId]; tree[id].d += (value);`

(PS: Pseudo code is mentioned)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because that `unordered_map<int32_t,Node>` tries to call the constructor Node() with no argument, and because you defined the constructor with three argument, Node() is deleted. Consider adding `Node()=default;` inside the class definition.